# How to get the registration token on start using the InstanceIDListenerService

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the "new" way of obtaining a registrationID as described in: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

However there is one thing I don't get. Apparently the benefit of using this way is that the app does not continuously have to check it's registration token. In my app I want to get the token as soon as the app starts. And then use my InstanceIDListenerService to handle the refresh of a registration token.

At the moment I achieve this by kicking off the intent that will get the registration token on start:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myRegistrationIntentService.class);
startService(intent);
```

I feel like this is not the way to do this. But how should I implement this. All Google says is not to do it in the main thread but use the intent instead.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with doing it that way

Comment: but now I will query this every time the MainActivity is called. Should I manually keep track whether I already have a registration token?

Comment: the only time you need to manually update it is when you update your app, if it changes between then, the `onTokenRefresh()` of your instance id listener should get called

Comment: Then what checks should I do before I start the intent from the main activity? If I already have the token on my server and if the app has been updated?

Comment: just check if your app was updated